# Replacing multiple words in a string with preg_replace does not seem to work

Tags: php, regex

Code:

```
$testing="sniper this and sniper that";
$connectors=array('and', 'now', 'but', 'still', 'so', 'only', 'therefore', 'moreover', 'besides', 'consequently','nevertheless', 'for', 'however', 'hence', 'either', 'or', 'neither', 'nor', 'both', 'also','while', 'then', 'who', 'which', 'that', 'although', 'though', 'since', 'until', 'as', 'if','after', 'before', 'how', 'once', 'when', 'lest', 'why', 'unless', 'because', 'till', 'where', 'whether','the', 'a', 'an','about', 'above', 'across', 'after', 'against', 'along', 'among', 'around', 'at', 'before', 'behind','below', 'beneath', 'beside', 'between', 'beyond', 'but', 'by', 'despite', 'down', 'during', 'except','for', 'from', 'in', 'inside', 'into', 'like', 'near', 'of', 'off', 'on', 'onto', 'out', 'outside', 'over',
        'past', 'since', 'through', 'throughout', 'till', 'to', 'toward', 'under', 'underneath', 'until', 'up', 'upon','with', 'within', 'without','who', 'whom', 'whose', 'which', 'that', 'this', 'these', 'those', 'I', 'Me', 'You', 'He', 'him', 'she','her', 'it', 'we', 'us', 'they', 'them', 'Mine', 'Yours', 'His', 'Hers', 'Its', 'Ours', 'Theirs', 'whoever','whomever', 'whichever', 'myself', 'yourself', 'himself', 'herself', 'itself','ourselves', 'yourselves', 'themselves');

foreach($connectors as $word)
{
    $pattern="/".strtolower($word)."/";
    $data=preg_replace($pattern,"/ /", $testing);
}
echo $data."<br>";
echo $testing;
```

Output:

> sniper this and sniper that
>
> sniper this and sniper that

Expected output:

> sniper this and sniper that
>
> sniper sniper

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If any, then the expected output should be reversed. You are echoing the changed data first and then the original data.

Comment: Why do you expect output "sniper this and sniper that sniper sniper"? Your code (does not -- see below) replace each word from the $connectors array by "/ /", therefore, you would be correctly expecting the output "sniper / / / / sniper / /". However, the problem is that you operate preg_replace on $testing (which remains unchanged). So, you'd have to put a statement $data = $testing;, and your replace stmt would be $data=preg_replace($pattern, "/ /", $data); Anyway, I assume you might want to replace "/ /" by "".

Comment: Thanks @polkageist. Did those changes. Makes sense. However instead of sniper sniper now I get sn per sn per. The problem is "I" is one of the connectors and that gets replaced in the word. How do I make it just replace single instances of "I" and not "i" in words?

Comment: Try changing your regexp to contain the "word boundary" modifier \b around your, word, i.e., $pattern='/\b('.strtolower($word).')/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$testing = "sniper this and sniper that";
$connectors = array( /* your data */ );

$output = implode(' ', array_diff(explode(' ', $testing), $connectors));
```

Case insensitive way:

```
$output = implode(' ', array_udiff(explode(' ', $testing), $connectors, 'strcasecmp'));
```

Comment: Hey hsz. How do I make this case insensitive?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you overwrite `$data` on each iteration.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need `/` in your replacement, unless of course you want to replace it with the string value `/ /`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
$testing = ......;
$connectors = array( ...... );
$data = str_ireplace( $connectors, " ", $testing);
echo $data."<br />".$testing;
```